# Updating Python record in a loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, django-models

Code: 
Models

```
class A1(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class A2(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User)
        field1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        field2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        field3 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Usage:

```
def insertRecord(modelName, fields, user)
    record = modelName(User=user, **fields)
    record.save()
```

Error: 'unicode' object is not callable.

Input: 
modelName: A2
fields: {u'field1': u'd2d2d2', u'field2': u'e2e2e2', u'field3': u'f2f2f2'} type(fields): 'dict'

Any solution/work around for this please ? 
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You have to set attributes:

```
def insertRecord(modelName, fields, user)
    if modelName == "A1":
        record = A1(User=user)
    else:
        record = A2(User=user)

    for field, value in fields.iteritems():
        setattr(record, field, value)
```

or simply:

```
def insert_record(model_name, fields, user):
    cls = A1 if model_name == 'A1' else A2
    return cls(User=user, **fields)
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. This helped a bit. But getting this as the error now: 'A2' object has no attribute '__getitem__' @Daniel

Comment: so what's your fields-argument?

Comment: Field arguments are all of type: field1 = models.CharField(max_length=200). I am getting 'unicode' object is not callable error. Updated Code above. @Daniel

Comment: Any Suggestions Please ?